# Notification area tool to manage Windows services

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-services

I have certain Windows services (mainly Apache, MySQL and Oracle) I need to use now and then. I prefer to have them disabled by default and start then manually when I want to use them.

Is there a tool that allows you to monitor and manage the Windows services you tell it to through the notification area? I basically expect one or more icons that:

- Show whether the services are running or not.
- Allow to start, stop or restart them quickly.
- Play well with User Account Control.

I thought there might exist such a generic tool out there but I couldn't find the appropriate keywords for Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Multi Service Controller](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Mutliservice-Controller-Download-105537.html) is something you're looking for, I can't seem to find any other application available.

EDIT: just found out it only manages services that you select manually in a list, I'll leave this answer here if you still want something like that.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I want: I'm only interested in a few specific services. I'll try it and report back. BTW, the official site appears to be http://mutliservice.codeplex.com/